# Two quantum observers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem, observers

It is considered that a quantum mechanics parameter is undefined until it is measured.But what happens if two independent observers measure the same quantum parameter?

Do they get the same value or for each observer it is two different values?

Comment: Do you assume that the measurements are done simultaneously?

Comment: @WeatherReport: I don't know

Answer (score 2):

When the first observer performs the measurement the result will be an eigenvalue of the corresponding observable being measured (e.g. if an electron's spin is measured the result will be either +1/2 or -1/2). Now the system is in the corresponding eigenstate of the observable which was measured (e.g., either spin-up or spin-down).
If this is also the eigenstate of the generator of the time evolution of the system (e.g., the Hamiltonian of the electron) then

1. if the second observer measures the same observable or one which has the same eigenstates as this observable then the result will be the same
   OR
2. If the second ob. measures an observable which does not commute with the first observable measured then the outcome will be random (e.g., the 2nd ob. measures spin in a different direction)

or if the eigenstate obtained by the first measurement is not an eigenstate of the generator of the time evolution then the system will continue to evolve and the state of the system measured presumably later after some time by the second observer will be different.

Glossary:

*State*- a vector (ray, more precisely) from the Hilbert space of all possible states of the system.

*Observable* - a Hermitian operator acting on the Hilbert space which corresponds to a physical quantity, such as momentum, position, spin, energy (aka Hamiltonian), etc. 
*Spin* - intrinsic angular momentum, an example of an observable

*Generator of the time evolution* - defines how the state changes in time. For closed systems (not interacting with their environment) it is just the Hamiltonian (whose eigenvalues correspond to possible results of measurement of energy).

Comment: I don't understand your terminology (I studied math in a university but have forgotten much if it.) Can you answer just like "yes" or "no" (the same value or different values)?

Comment: @porton There are several possibilities here so I can't answer with just yes or no. I will add a glossary of physical terms at the end of my answer.

Comment: Has this been done in an experimentally e.g. two observers trying to observe the position of an electron within a hydrogen nucleus using the same 'machine' at the same exact time, but doing so 180 degrees apart?